# sbyte[] column missing from database

Tags: entity-framework-5

I've defined my model as such:

```
class ImageSignature
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    [MaxLength(260)]
    [Required]
    public string FileName { get; set; }

    [MinLength(420)]
    [MaxLength(420)]
    [Required]
    public sbyte[] Signature { get; set; }
}
```

To which I add a bunch of entries:

```
static void BuildDb()
{
    Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<ImageContext>());
    // ....

    using (var db = new ImageContext())
    {
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            var sig = new ImageSignature
            {
                FileName = file,
                Signature = Signature(file),
            };

            db.Images.Add(sig);

        }
        try
        {
            records = db.SaveChanges(); 
        }
        catch (DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
        {
            // ....
        }

    }

    Console.WriteLine("Saved {0} entities", records);
}
```

Which outputs "Saved 133 entities".

It creates a `database.mdf` file as expected, but when I look at it in Server Explorer the "Signature" column is missing, and when I loop over the data, Signature always comes back null.

Where is my column? How do I get it to save my data?

Comment: What happens if you use byte array instead? I think EF does not support signed byte array.

Comment: @LadislavMrnka: I tried that... can't remember what happened now. I think I got the field to show up in the DB but it the values still came back null. Shouldn't EF throw an exception if it doesn't support the data type rather than silently tossing your data away? Can I write a value converter?

Comment: No EF will not throw an exception and you currently cannot write a value converter. Byte array should work.